# How can I create a Google Compute Engine VM image from a Docker image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Node.js app Docker image stored in the Google Container Registry, and I want to use it as the basis for a new Google Compute Engine VM image for development purposes, with all the necessary dependencies pre-installed. What is the best way to achieve this? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a Docker image to create a virtual machine or physical computer.

A Docker image does not contain an operating system. A Docker image requires an operating system or subsystem to run under.